# Flutter Override Parent Route's Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an AppBar widget at the top of my widget tree. I want to "override" this AppBar by a child's Widget's appbar. I looked up InheritedWidget, yet did not like it because I don't prefer to manage states all the time. How can I efficiently - with a minimal amount of code - overcome this problem.

**main.dart**

```
... Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: 'My App'), body: ChildPage())
      ........
```

---

**child_page.dart**

```
... Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: 'My App'), leading: ..., actions: ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a parent screen with multiple subscreens that share the parent screen properties and customize them.

First of all, you should not have more than one Scaffold for a single screen/route according to the [API Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html).

> The Scaffold is designed to be a top-level container for a MaterialApp. This means that adding a Scaffold to each route on a Material app will provide the app with Material's basic visual layout structure.

So the short answer to your question is there is no way to accomplish exactly what you are asking for.

There are some alternatives though.

- You can extract the AppBar into a widget or method.
- A better alternative (which can be applicable to pretty much everything in your app) is to define an app theme with all the properties you want your AppBar to have and then override these properties on each screen.

A simple example:

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      elevation: 0,
    ),
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
);
```